# Java reading hex file

Tags: java, file-io, hex

As part of a larger program, I need to read values from a hex file and print the decimal values.
It seems to be working fine; However all hex values ranging from 80 to 9f are giving wrong values.
for example 80 hex gives a decimal value of 8364
Please help.

this is my code :

```
String filename = "pidno5.txt";
FileInputStream ist = new FileInputStream("sb3os2tm1r01897.032");       
BufferedReader istream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ist));
int b[]=new int[160];       
for(int i=0;i<160;i++)
    b[i]=istream.read();
for(int i=0;i<160;i++)
    System.out.print((b[i])+" ");
```

Comment: Just for terminology: You are not reading a **hex file** (which would be a file containing hexadecimal data coded in ASCII?), but a **binary file**.

Answer (score 7):

If you were trying to read raw bytes this is not what you are doing.

You are using a Reader, which reads characters (in an encoding you did not specify, so it defaults to something, maybe UTF-8).

To read bytes, use an InputStream (and do not wrap it in a Reader).

Comment: The default encoding is probably some Microsoft code page, as some of them have the € sign on code point 0x80, which is then mapped to Unicode 8364.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a different encoding:

```
BufferedReader istream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ist, "ISO-8859-15"));
```